# How to ignore cells with dates when adding entire rows

Tags: excel, date, cell

I have an inventory tracking sheet, it subtracts from the inventory count on all items from that row, ignoring cells with text on them.

I want it to ignore cells with dates on them but entering things like 01/14/2016 throws the whole thing off because it counts them as a number.

this is my current code "=SUM(C5-SUMIF(I5:BZ5, "<> *ORD", I5:BZ5))"

so every time I have an order I will input 3 rowcells, for example:

```
I5 = "ORDER 45", 
J5 = "01/16/2016",
K5 = "5",
```

K5 will be the actual piece count that will be subtracted from the inventory in C5

picture for reference

[image: http://s11.postimg.org/f46gs6n1v/New_Bitmap_Image.png]

Comment: Will any one number be greater than 40,000?

Comment: `=C5-SUMIFS(I5:BZ5,I5:BZ5, "<> *ORD", I5:BZ5,"<40000")` will exclude all dates after 07/06/2009.  It will also exclude any number over that.  You can lower it to what ever threshold you want.

Comment: No, the maximum pieces they take a time is like 200ish at the most, I doubt it will ever break 1000 pcs.

Comment: Then: `=C5-SUMIFS(I5:BZ5,I5:BZ5, "<> *ORD*", I5:BZ5,"<10000")` Will do what you want.